# how do i make a batch program that types

Tags: windows, batch-file

hi i am interested in making a batch program that allows me to be able to place my cursor anywhere and have the batch program type for me as if i'm typing. i have looked at a lot of different sites for help but it might be it's impossible with batch programming or i just need someone on here to tell me how your input is much appreciated. i have tried to use echo >>etc .text commands but that only inserts input into that specific text document. I would like to know this because it would improve my batch programming and would be a valuable tool to have.

Comment: I think you will have to use `ANSI sequences` to position the cursor and so on, checkout: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php

Comment: You would be much better of doing this is a actual prgramming language (Batch is a scripting language designed for automating tasks like file organsising). I would personally recommend you use C#. You could make a program that could input text as if your keyboard typed it, and that would automatically put it to where your cursor is. Note if you clicked in Windows explorer, it would keep on selecting files starting with the letter inputted.

Comment: I suggest autohotkey!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a bit of thinking, the only way to do this is to update the clipboard with whatever you want to "type" into the program, and then press "Ctrl + V" to paste it. The way you would go about inmplementing this is up to you, but to place something in the clipboard via batch is:

```
 Clip < file.txt
```

And you would have to make a batch file which would continuosly update the clipboard with whatever you wanted to paste. The way you do this is up to you.

Other then that, I dont see any other way you could do something like this in batch. Like I mentioned your better off doing this in C#.

Mona